# Can customer support be "technically minded"?

Tags: meaning

I’m working in an enterprise that has a customer support department. In most marketing materials, we're presenting ourselves as having a technically-minded customer support team. It’s done to indicate that the team will be able to assist our clients with various technical questions.

It seems that technically-minded refers more to their character traits rather than a service they’re performing. I also think that such a definition may confuse readers, who would understand the matter easier if the team was called "tech support".

What do you guys think?

Comment: Technically minded sounds aspirational. Technical is what I'd want as a customer.

Comment: Does your team handle only tech support or do they also handle other customer issues?

Comment: "technically minded" is a commonly used phrase. Are you asking what it means or do you have some other question?

Comment: When it is the same sentence as *Customer Support* the character is not what they think of but the skills and service. I agree with Yosef regarding aspirations.

Answer (score 1):

Many organizations have separate technical support and customer support departments. Technical support helps with using the products, customer support deals with other issues like billing, starting/canceling service, etc.

"teechnically-minded customer support" indicates that there's just a single support team that's the first point of contact by the customer. They will try to help with technical issues as well as normal customer support, but may need to escalate to a team of experts for complicated technical issues.

"-minded" is a qualifier that means they're not *really* technical, but they try to think that way.